# MATLAB file formats: bit format?

Tags: matlab

I have a file that was generated in MATLAB by someone else.  That file size is 382 bytes.  If I load that file into MATLAB, it creates a array with size 30x30x30 of type uint8.  The elements of the array are either one or zero (mostly zero).

I want to store the same exact data into another file and have it be the same exact size, but I don't know how.  If I write the array to another file with type 'int8', then the output file will be 27 kbytes in size.  If I use type 'bit1', then the output file will be 4 kbytes.  How can I regenerate the exact same file with the same size as the original?

Here is how I'm saving the file:

```
filenameOut = 'newFile.mat';
fileID1 = fopen(filenameOut, 'w', 's');
fwrite(fileID1, arrName, 'bit1');
fclose(fileID1);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are trying to save the new data? Is it still a .mat file? 382 bytes is only possible if the array is written as a sparse array, while 27 kB suggests the full array is being written to the file (27000 values at 1 byte each).

Comment: It is still a .mat file.  4 KB suggests one bit per element.  How does one write sparse arrays?

Comment: The MAT-file format is compressed. If you apply ZIP compression to your file you probably will get close to 382 bytes.

Comment: Try saving the file with `save('newFile.mat', 'arrName')`, that should give you a compressed MAT-file as Cris mentioned. I think using the `fwrite` function as you demonstrated is writing the "full" matrix to the file instead.

Comment: Can you also give the commands you use to load the original file?

Comment: Assuming that the variable laoded from the file is named `var`, you can try to save it with `save myFile.mat var -v7` and  `save myFile_nocomp.mat var -v7 -nocompression`. You will then see the effect of the ZIP compression mentionned by @Chris Luengo on the file size. The `-nocompression` flag is available on recent releases of Matlab.